# how to remove redundant use of last keyword in qsql

Tags: kdb

I have a table:

```
q)t:([] sym:`AAPL`MSFT`AMZN`AAPL`MSFT`AMZN; px:1 2 3 11 22 33; sh:100 200 300 1000 2000 3000)
```

I want to get the last px and sh by sym which can be obtained using last function two times:

```
q)select last px, last sh by sym from t
sym | px sh
----| -------
AAPL| 11 1000
AMZN| 33 3000
MSFT| 22 2000
```

How can we use last keyword only once to get above output?(Because in practical cases sometimes we need to use last on more than 30 columns)

My Failed attempts:

```
q)select last (px;sh) by sym from t
q)select {last x}@'(px;sh) by sym from t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach to the problem is to use `fby` which allows you to apply a function such as `first` or `last` (or a lambda) across all columns:

```
t:([]c1:10?`A`B`C;c2:10?10;c3:10?"xyz";c4:.z.D-til 10)

q)select from t where i=(last;i)fby c1
c1 c2 c3 c4
-------------------
A  9  z  2019.10.01
C  7  y  2019.09.29
B  0  x  2019.09.28

q)select from t where i=({first x};i)fby c1
c1 c2 c3 c4
-------------------
B  6  x  2019.10.07
C  6  x  2019.10.06
A  4  y  2019.10.02
```

To answer your question in a comment regarding applying a different function per column, you would have to use a functional select such as:

```
q)?[t;();{x!x}1#`c1;{x!((first;last)x in `c2`c4),'x}cols[t]except`c1]
c1| c2 c3 c4
--| ----------------
A | 9  y  2019.10.01
B | 0  x  2019.09.28
C | 7  x  2019.09.29
```

This uses `last` for columns c2 and c4, then uses `first` for the other columns

Answer (score 6):

For cases like this, using a by phrase together with no selection of columns is the same as applying last to all columns.

```
select by sym from t
```

Should do the trick

```
q)(select last px, last sh by sym from t)~select by sym from t
1b
```

Comment: if we have to fetch 100 columns from a table, from that table - for 25 columns we want the last value and for 15 columns we need first value then how can that be done?

Comment: You could possible do something like:

```select last@/:(col1;col2), first@/:(col3;col4) by sym from t```

Comment: If the table is known to be monotonic in time, this is the best solution to the given question. It is the most concise and will run much faster

Comment: @Utsav I think Terry's answer is best way of going about it if you are looking to apply anything but last to your columns.